# Exception when using console window in a form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program WFA that also has and command Window. I open the window with AllocConsole(); When I close the console window, I use FreeConsole(); but when I open it again with AllocConsole(); I wanna write and read from it and it throws an exception.
The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

class classx
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 AllocConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool AttachConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool GetConsoleWindow();
    public static bool z = false;
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine HandlerRoutine, bool Add);
    public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(uint dwControlType);
}



public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    NotifyIcon icontask;
    Icon iconone_active;
    Icon iconone_inactive;
    /*Icon icontwo;
    Icon iconthree;
    Icon iconfour;
    Icon iconfive;*/
    Thread Threadworkermy;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        iconone_active = new Icon(".../iconone_active.ico");
        iconone_inactive = new Icon(".../iconone_inactive.ico");
        icontask = new NotifyIcon();
        icontask.Icon = iconone_active;
        icontask.Visible = true;
        Threadworkermy = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkActivityThread));
        Threadworkermy.Start();

        MenuItem Nameapp = new MenuItem("xr");
        MenuItem quitappitem = new MenuItem("quit program");
        MenuItem OpenGUI = new MenuItem("Open GUI");
        MenuItem Advancedmodewindow = new MenuItem("x");
        ContextMenu contextmenu = new ContextMenu();

        quitappitem.Click += quitappitem_click;
        OpenGUI.Click += OpenGUI_click;
        Advancedmodewindow.Click += Advancedmodewindow_click;
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(Nameapp);
        contextmenu.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false;
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(OpenGUI);
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(Advancedmodewindow);
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(quitappitem);
        icontask.ContextMenu = contextmenu;

        icontask.Icon = iconone_active;
        icontask.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Advancedmodewindow_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classx.AllocConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("X");
        classx.FreeConsole();
    }

    private void OpenGUI_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;  
    }

    private void quitappitem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Threadworkermy.Abort();
        icontask.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void checkActivityThread()
    {
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);   
            }
        } catch(ThreadAbortException tbe)
        {

        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }


}
}
```

Exception that it throws out 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The handle is invalid.
To those who will be saying to change the type, I can't. (it needs to be WFA application)

Why doesn't

```
CONSOLE.WRITELINE
```

and similar code work?

Answer (score 3):

The exception is not coming from Open/Close the console. It's coming when you want to write/read something with the console. You have to **RESET** the standard IO for your console. Every time you have to do this after AllocConsole(). Please check below code, it's tested.

CODE:

```
private void Advancedmodewindow_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classx.AllocConsole();

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()) { AutoFlush = true };
    Console.SetOut(writer);

    Console.WriteLine("X");

    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()));
    string line = Console.ReadLine();

    classx.FreeConsole();
}
```

Comment: how to do inputs then because when i try to input with Console.ReadLine(); it throws same exception

Comment: If this works for Writes, then for reads you need to duplicate the code and instead of StreamWriter, use StreamReader

Comment: Thx will put it in my code as soon as i get back on pc

Comment: And sorry to see that the answer is not accepted yet.